Command line redering problem: System is out of GPU and shared host memory
I am doing command line rendering on two computers:
PC1 has these specs:
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070-8GB and 32GB of RAM
And PC2 has these specs:
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti-11GB and 32GB of RAM
I do the command line rendering this way:
.\blender -b testFile.blend -o /output -E CYCLES -s 10 -e 20 -a -- --cycles-device OPTIX+CPU -y

On PC1, rendering goes fine, and the Peak memory usage is like this:
Fra:10 Mem:15747.26M (Peak 16677.02M) | Time:01:18.26 | Compositing | De-initializing execution

While on PC2, I get the error:
System is out of GPU and shared host memory
And the memory usage Peak is like this:
Fra:10 Mem:12906.41M (Peak 12906.41M) | Time:01:43.03 | Mem:2763.73M, Peak:2763.73M | Scene, Living | Updating Images | Loading whitemarble_3_basecolor-2K.png

Before running the rendering, I do a check to see the available GPU memory and system memory, and those are the results:
PC1: Total system RAM: 32 - Available system  RAM: 24
GPU: {'id': 0, 'name': 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070', 'load': 0.06, 'free_memory': 7066.0, 'used_memory': 941.0, 'total_memory': 8192.0, 'temperature': 50.0}

PC2: Total system  RAM: 32 - Available system  RAM: 28
GPU: [{'id': 0, 'name': 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti', 'load': 0.0, 'free_memory': 10639.0, 'used_memory': 389.0, 'total_memory': 11264.0, 'temperature': 40.0}]

So as it seems, PC2 has more memory to work with, but it still gives System Out of Memory error. While PC1 works perfectly.
I tried to run the rendering command without +CPU flag, but it did not help.
I also tried to do the rendering with Blender 3.6.9 and 4.0.2 but both had the same results.
Both machines run Windows 11, and the Nvidia driver is up to date on both PCs.
What could be the problem?
